Having problem installing Sherlock
I am trying to download Sherlock but getting the errors below.
My command ------> $ git clone https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock
Errors received:
Cloning into 'sherlock'  
remote: Enumerating objects: 9472, done.  
remote: Counting objects: 100% (218/218), done.  
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (146/146), done.  
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.  
error: 14298 bytes of body are still expected  
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet  
fatal: early EOF  
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output  


This question is about a package that is in the default Ubuntu repositories,  not about Kali Linux as a reviewer mistakenly assumed without checking. Admittedly the kali-linux-tools tag that was used to tag this question is a bit confusing.

To install sherlock in Ubuntu 24.04 and later open the terminal and type:
sudo apt install sherlock

sherlock is a tool that is used to find usernames across social networks. I'm reasonably confident that it would also be possible to install the sherlock package from Ubuntu 24.04 in earlier versions of Ubuntu. Please comment if this happens to be the case here.
